# Having SSHD while using an SSD working on AHCI mode

Tags: ssd, raid, cache, ahci, hybrid-storage

So I have an SSD working on AHCI mode.

I'm planning to add an SSHD to my rig, so the question is do I have to change SATA controller to RAID mode when I got my SSHD? (to enable its Built-in SSD caching)

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: I'm using my SSD as OS disk, and I want to replace my HDDs with a single SSHD to be as fast. I could dedicate some of my SSD storage as cache to one of my HDDs though, but I got 2 HDDs, and I'm not sure if I can install my OS on SSDs remaning free space. Another thing is my SSD is only 120GB and I need all of it. Things can get pretty messed up, and that's why I think of getting an SSHD

Comment: If you need all of your SSD then you shouldn't be using the majority of it for a cache when the SSHD has that capability built into and is the entire point I would presume your going with said SSHD solution.

Comment: Yes, that's why I think of buying an SSHD.

Answer (score 1):

If you are buying a standalone SSHD with built-in SSD caching then no, as it is part of the drive and nothing to do with the SATA controller.

If you are buying a standard HDD to use with your existing SSD to create a SSHD yourself, then yes, that functionality requires RAID mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually getting rid of my old 1TB and 3TB HDDs, and buying a 4TB SSHD with 8GBs of SSD as cache. So SSD Caching on SSHDs has nothing to do with Intel's Smart Response Technology?

Comment: I got my answer clearly, but I want to know has anybody practiacally tried this before (having SSD and SSHD on a system working under AHCI mode), and was the result as said in the answer?

Comment: Yes. And as I said a SSHD has nothing to do with the SATA controller so what mode it is in is irrelevant.